# Undefined variable javascript; While actually defined

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm having trouble with this code:

```
google.charts.load('current', {
    packages: ['corechart', 'line']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function time(dati) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            dati = [];
            dati.push(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
            console.log(dati); //logs perfectly fine
            return dati;
        };
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "graph-data.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
};
time();
console.log(dati); // logs nothing

function drawBasic(dati) {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'X');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Prijs');

    console.log(dati); //logs nothing

    data.addRows(dati);

    var options = {
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Time'
        },
        vAxis: {
            title: 'Prijs'
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

The variables are not defined. How do I define them?

Comment: post your error

Comment: Why do you print console.log(dati); outside time-function?

Comment: @ricky data.js:17 Uncaught ReferenceError: dati is not defined

Comment: @Blauharley but I did? on line 17

Comment: @PDek: Was the other way around ;)

Comment: You do understand that time function expects a parameter `dati`? You're calling the function without passing that parameter.

Comment: @PDek: Blauharley's question was **why** did you do that.

Comment: @Blauharley haha sorry, it is just a debugging method? testing where my code goes wrong

Comment: You can use any indentation and such you like in your code, but when asking for help, please post code that is indented reasonably and consistently. I've fixed it for you this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting that error because `dati` is an undeclared variable you're trying to take the value of on Line 17:

```
console.log(dati);
```

There is no in-scope `dati` identifier where that code appears. You have a `dati` *parameter* inside your `time` function, but that's only inside your `time` function; the line above is outside it.

Once you've fixed that problem, your next problem is covered here: [*How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) `time` *starts* an asynchronous operation that won't be completed yet when `time` returns.

You also seem to be expecting `setOnLoadCallback` to pass something to your `drawBasic` function:

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);
```

I can't find the docs for it (!!), but [this page's examples](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference) don't show the functions called by it accepting any parameters.

---

Guessing a bit, but I suspect you wanted to do something like this; see inline comments:

```
// A scoping function so we don't create globals
(function() {
    // Variables for the data and a loaded flag
    var dati = null;
    var loaded = false;

    // A function we can call from both async operations to see if both have completed
    function checkReady() {
        if (dati && loaded) {
            // They're both done, we can draw
            drawBasic(dati);
        }
    }

    // Load charts and get callback when done
    google.charts.load('current', {
        packages: ['corechart', 'line']
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
        loaded = true;
        checkReady();
    });

    // Load our data
    function time() { // <== Note no `dati` parameter, we want to use the variable declared above
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                // Fill in the data -- are you sure you really want an array with the data
                // as its only entry?
                dati = [];
                dati.push(JSON.parse(this.responseText));

                // If we're ready, draw
                checkReady();
            };
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "graph-data.php", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    };
    time(); // Start the data load

    function drawBasic(dati) {

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('number', 'X');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Prijs');

        console.log(dati); //logs nothing

        data.addRows(dati);

        var options = {
            hAxis: {
                title: 'Time'
            },
            vAxis: {
                title: 'Prijs'
            }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
})(); // The end of the scoping function, and `()` to invoke it
```

I'm sure that's not perfect, but hopefully it gets you going the right way.